Data entry for 2 related tables with form, automatically input foreign key into main table
Working in MS Access.
I am developing a customer loyalty database and I have 2 tables:
Customers



Names
Admission
Creation_Date
Expiry_Date
Contact_ID




John Smith
Adult
01/02/2024
01/02/2025
1



Contact



ID
Mobile
Email
Address




1
0400 123 456
John.smith@gmail.com
12 John St, Candyland 1234



In some cases, multiple customers will have the same contact information. Hence why I have separated the data into 2 related tables.
I am trying to create a form in order to enter new customers into the database.
It will need to contain all of the fields from both tables and every time a new customer is being entered with new contact information, I want the new primary key of the new contact information, to be automatically linked and inputted into the 'Contact ID' field on my 'Customers' DB.
I have tried (unsuccessfully) having the Contact details on a bound main from and the Customers details on a sub-form. I hoped that I would be able to build a macro that, on a button press, would copy the primary key ('ID') of the contact details into the 'Contact_ID' field in the sub-form.
The main form (bound to Contact) is called 'New'.
The sub-form (bound to Customers) is called 'sub_info'
I have tried to a SetProperty macro:
Control Name: = [Forms]![New]![sub_info].[Form]![sub_Contact_ID]
Property: Value
Value: =[Forms]![New]![ID_Contact]

I have also tried an unbound form with multiple SQL INSERT queries.
I tried to INSERT the Contact info first and then execute SELECT to find the MAX(ID) from Contact and return it that value to a textbox, and then execute another INSERT on Customers using the returned ID from the textbox.
The problem with that was running the queries in the macro builder which kept throwing errors at me.
I want to know if i am referencing an object on the sub-form wrong, or if that will not work/is not the right way to do it.
Or if there is a much simpler way to automatically connect the data
Any help or suggestions much appreciated!!

I found a solution way simpler than what I was trying to do.
I made a new form with all bound controls on the one form, the used the AfterUpdate event on the 'ID' control to copy the ID into the 'Control_ID' control.
